# How to know when an iframe is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, domready

I have an iframe inside a web page, and I want to do something when it is ready. I tried 2 ways:

- In the parent page, I use this

  ```
  jQuery('#iframe').load(function() {
   //my code here
  });
  ```

this code will be executed when the iframe is finished loading (as I wanted), but because my iframe is pointed to another domain, so at this point, I can't access its content (cross domain problem)

- Inside the iframe, I use this:

  ```
   jQuery('body').ready(function() {
   });
  ```

This code is executed when the iframe starts loading, which is much earlier than I want, so the code can not function properly.

So how I execute code when the iframe is finished loading and ready for DOM-manipulation

I searched and found that easyXDM may be the solution, but I wonder if there is simpler solution exists.

Thank you.

Comment: Since it's cross-domain, it's never going to be ready for DOM manipulation unless you disable the cross-domain policy in your browser.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `$(function() { });` should work perfectly fine inside the iframe. You cannot manipulate it from the parent document anyway. So it should already work with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

dont't use jquery,It will make your javascript knowledge confusion,

You can use the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(){
        var iframe=document.getElementById('aa');
        var h=iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
        alert(h)    
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="aa" src="3.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="200" onload="show()"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: From the question: *"my iframe is pointed to another domain"*... you cannot access the content of an iframe from another domain, regardless whether you use jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to know when the iframe is ready AND you want to access content from that iframe cross-domain, I think easyXDM would be a good choice.

You could basically implement [this example](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/setting-up-your-first-socket/), and simply add your code to the "onReady" method.